# PDF viewer to get the co-ordinates of selected text

Tags: java, pdf, eclipse-plugin, pdfbox

I know that PDFBox can be used to extract text from PDF.
But my question is whether it is possible to select some text from a PDF viewer and get the co-ordinates of the same with some open source pdf viewers?

Comment: To answer that, one has to know what information your pdf viewer returns when you query it for its selection. Please explain.

Comment: If i can get the co-ordinates of the rectangle from the PDF viewer, i can get the text extracted.
But the problem is how can i get the co-ordinates of the selected rectangle from the viewer.
Can i make such a viewer with the help of PDFBox to get the selection co-ordinates?
Or is there any such open source viewers already available?

Comment: *But the problem is how can i get the co-ordinates of the selected rectangle from the viewer* - well, if that is your question, you should ask so.  Neither the heading of your question nor is text nor is tags say so.

Comment: Sorry! I will updated it. But can you please lead me in the right direction. I am totally confused. I came across a library called JPedal.
But its not returning the exact co-ordinates.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't... I do know my way around with some **PDF libraries** (for PDF creation / manipulation) but I don't know much about specific **PDF viewer** behavior. The original formulation of your question made me think I could help but unfortunately I can not.